# How to hide a whole a <div> if table <td> tag is is empty or null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, thymeleaf

Currently I am using thymeleaf as a view. I am trying to hide my div if all of my table  tags are null or empty. If it is not empty then show the div that will show the table.

**Simple Html :**

```
<div id= "myTable1div">
   <h3> Test table </h3>

   <table id="Table1">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr th:each="data, iterStat : ${hostlist}">
         <td th:text = "${data.host}"></td>
         <td th:text = "${data.id}"></td> 
         <td th:text = "${data.number}"></td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

How can I write a javascript, css or Jquery if td is null hide this div?
Basically this would show a table with a header. But if the  tags are null it should be just a blank page. Showing nothing that is inside the  tag.

Comment: If one `td` is "null or empty" or all the `td`'s??

Comment: Why not Thymeleaf?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki if all the td are null or empty.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I can hide a div tag with thyme leaf?

Comment: Yes, but I'm confused by your markup because it seems you're only loading a single element in the table. So, are you wanting to not show the *row* if one element is completely null/empty or the div?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I want the whole div tag to hide if <td> values are null or blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if one of `td`'s are *empty* or *null* in the ready function using `each()` method then hide the div  using `hide()` :

```
$(function(){
   var hide = true;

   $('#Table1 td').each(function(){
        var td_content = $(this).text();

        if(td_content!=""){
            hide = false;
        }
   })

   if(hide){
      $('#myTable1div').hide();
   }
})
```

Hope this helps.

**Two empty `td`'s case :**

```js
$(function(){
  var hide = true;

  $('#Table1 td').each(function(){
    var td_content = $(this).text();

    if(td_content!=""){
      hide = false;
    }
  })

  if(hide){
    $('#myTable1div').hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myTable1div">
  <table id="Table1">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th> 
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td> 
      <td>number</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**All `td`'s are empty case :**

```js
$(function(){
  var hide = true;

  $('#Table1 td').each(function(){
    var td_content = $(this).text();

    if(td_content!=""){
      hide = false;
    }
  })

  if(hide){
    $('#myTable1div').hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myTable1div">
  <table id="Table1">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th> 
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated my answer so the table will be hidden _if all the td are null or empty._

Comment: This code works but when I have a table row tag like <tr th:each="listValue, iterStat : ${datalist}" th:if="${listValue.Status == 'CRITICAL'}"> which outputs nothing because status currently do not equal CRITICAL. This div tag does not disappear.

Comment: Could you please show me how it looks in the browser (PURE HTML), after the compilation.

Comment: Using pure HTML your method works. But when I have the thyme leaf tag to dynamically insert data into the table cells It does not work. It just does not hide the div tag.

Comment: Yes i see and i believe you.. i would just to see how the HTML look like after the compilation of 'thyme leaf' tags, (use inspector in your browser to get the `tr` that not disappear in you current code from active page)

Comment: added image of what I am doing and getting

Comment: So close.. i want to see the tbody part also in the inspector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129815/discussion-between-jackie-and-zakaria-acharki).

Answer (score 1):

Although all the answers here would probably work, they are all tightly coupled (a simple html change will most like stop the javascript code from working as intended) and not reusable.  I would recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - Philip Walton @ Google Engineer](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

If I were to write this, it would probably look a little bit like:

```
<div id= "myTable1div" class="js-hide-onallempty">
  <table id="Table1">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th> 
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="js-hide-onallempty-data">${data.host}</td>
      <td class="js-hide-onallempty-data">${data.id}</td> 
      <td class="js-hide-onallempty-data">${data.number}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".js-hide-onallempty").each(function(){
    var $hide = $(this);
    var isHidden = true;
    $hide.find('.js-hide-onallempty-data').each(function(){
      isHidden = $(this).text().trim().length == 0;
      return isHidden;  // if any element has text then this return false
                        // and breaks the loop
    });
    $hide.toggle(isHidden);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are printing the variables ${data.host}.
Why not check if ${data.host} is empty. if so do not display the table.

In jQuery this can be done as

```
if(typeof data.host === undefined || data.host === '' || data.host === null) 
    $("#Table1").hide();
else
    // display the table with the data
```

In vanilla js it can be done like this

```
if(typeof data.host === undefined || data.host === '' || data.host === null) 
    $(document.querySelector("#Table1")).style.display = "none";
else
    // display the table with the data
```